# Leaflet.draw geojson layer edit

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

As you see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3EQ9X/7/) , I have a polygon like this:

```
var data = [{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [2.504410743713379,44.28253972334941],
        [2.504410743713379,44.28929846767132],
        [2.5168561935424805,44.28929846767132],
        [2.5168561935424805,44.28253972334941],
        [2.504410743713379,44.28253972334941]
      ]
    ]
  }}]
```

When I want to add it to my featureGroup `drawnItems` I use:

```
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(data);
geojsonLayer.getLayers()[0].addTo(drawnItems);
```

Then I decide to edit polygon I can't move it because the central move handler does not appear, But when I draw new polygon using the toolbar I have move handler.
[image]

Could you please help me?
how can I add my polygon to have move handler?

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution to the problem?

Comment: Yes, I came up with a solution. I fixed it by creating a new polygon manually instead of adding a GeoJSON layer directly to the feature group. Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this to add every Geojson layer to drawnItems:

```
var geeoojson = L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(data), {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.addTo(drawnItems);
    }
}).addTo(map)
```